# redis-sentinel: config rewrite vs. ansible

Tags: redis, ansible

I try to write an ansible role for redis/sentinel and am stuck at one point:
Since sentinel writes create config rewrites, the config always changes which triggers always changes
A way out could be to to configure sentinel to write the CONFIG REWRITE in another file and include that one in the main redis.conf
Is this possible somehow ? Or are there any other methods to not have the changes in the main redis.conf